# Can Appium automate mobile apps build on Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to automate the App build using Titanium Appcelerator.
When I'm inspecting elements using UIAutomator I'm not able to find the resource-id. I'm using path as a workaround but this is not a long term solution.

Has anyone worked with Appcelerator and Appium and is able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to use Appium with Appcelerator Titanium!  The key is using the `accessibilityLabel` property on your views.

i.e. `<Label id="label1"  accessibilityLabel="label1" text="I am label1" />`

You can then do something like this in your Appium tests:

```
it('should have label1', function() {
    return driver
        .elementByAccessibilityId('label1')
        .should.eventually.exist
        .getAttribute('value')
        .should.become('I am label1');
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions about it!  I will probably together a [blog post about it here](https://brenton.house) because I know a lot of other devs have the same questions you have.